# Active 2nd order elliptic filter design reference

Tags: audio

Can anyone share a design reference for an active differential 2nd order elliptic filter?  This is for audio applications.

I need an elliptic response with 0.5 dB pass band ripple and -40dB/decade attenuation in the stop band.

Comment: if you can share the response that you need from it

Comment: Without any other details, this question is as vague as they come. There are programs that deal with this kind of design, already. Searching for "elliptic filter design" brings up quite a few results. Otherwise, it's up to you to know how to calculate the poles and zeroes in order to make the transfer function, and what opamp topology you find best for your application in order to convert the transfer function to a realizable circuit.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [microcap v12](http://www.spectrum-soft.com/download/mc12cd.zip), Filter Design option.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with reading some relevant AN for active differential filters. TI has SLOA054 and LT Journal January 2014 has an article for their part. SLYT343 outlines the conversion process from single to differential.

For par condicio Analog says [this](https://ez.analog.com/amplifiers/differential-amplifiers/f/q-a/538835/how-to-use-a-differential-amplifier-to-design-active-filter)

Not excessively difficult but *some* math is needed (if you already know what is as elliptic filter you'll be fine I guess). The process itself is *trivial* (just use the same feedback on both sides)

Comment: No that is not easy as your thinking and your mentioned AN is not having data related to filters

Comment: @narendraallu the link contains a link to Filterwizard